# How can I use the unmanaged UI Automation API from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dll, com, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

The UI Automation API for Windows is available from two DLLs.
One is a managed DLL, which is `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\UIAutomationClient.dll`.
The other is an unmanaged DLL, which is `C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll`.
According to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f3bbec4d-f7c6-4e66-8d74-9d3db562a6c3/ui-automation-cannot-find-an-element-inspect-object-can?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation), the unmanaged API is superior to the managed API in terms of the number of visible elements, so I would like to use the unmanaged API.

I have tried three approaches, but all of them failed.
Would you tell me the correct approach?

## Approach #1: New-Object -ComObject

```powershell
$uia = New-Object -ComObject <ProgID of CUIAutomation>
$root = $uia.GetRootElement()
```

Failed because `New-Object` requires ProgID but [`CUIAutomation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384838(v=vs.85).aspx) does not have ProgID.

## Approach #2: Instantiation from CLSID

The CLSID of `CUIAutomation` is `ff48dba4-60ef-4201-aa87-54103eef594e`, then,

```powershell
$type = [Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID("ff48dba4-60ef-4201-aa87-54103eef594e")
$uia = [Activator]::CreateInstance($type)
$root = $uia.GetRootElement()
```

but failed with the following error message.
I still do not know why.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'GetRootElement'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $root = $uia.GetRootElement()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

## Approach #3: Add-Type

```powershell
Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll"
$uia = New-Object UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation
$root = $uia.GetRootElement()
```

Failed because `Add-Type` expects managed DLLs.

Error message:

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], BadImageFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

## Edit (2018-06-12)

I tried another approach. (and failed)

### Approach #4: Interop DLL

I do not really understand what exactly the Interop DLL is, but [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0ad8e71-a2a8-49af-9916-11005ce794ba/creating-some-powershell-cmdlets-for-managing-windows-updates-via-wuapilib#8041782c-9c37-4f3e-a7e7-819a41379809) says the Interop DLL helped OP anyway.
I installed Visual Studio and generated `Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll` by following the procedures of the post.

```powershell
Add-Type -Path "Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll"
$uia = New-Object UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomationClass
$root = $uia.GetRootElement()
$children = $root.FindAll([UIAutomationClient.TreeScope]::TreeScope_Children, $uia.CreateTrueCondition())
```

I succeeded in obtaining `$root`, but failed at the line of `$children` with the following error message.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'FindAll'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $children = $root.FindAll([UIAutomationClient.TreeScope]::TreeScope_C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I still do not know why.

Comment: Do you really want to do UI Automation from PowerShell? Why not Python+pywinauto which uses unmanaged UIAutomationCore.dll?

Comment: Regarding `FindAll` error, it looks like you need type conversion. `$root` is a base class object, not an AutomationElement object.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Actually it's OK if no need for admin rights of the production environment. It's not allowed to install Python or any other software which requires admin rights. For ease of maintenance, an interpreted language is preferred rather than a compiled language. So I think PowerShell is suitable. / I'll try type conversion later.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov `[UIAutomationClient.IUIAutomationElement]($root)` fails with `ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException` as `IUIAutomationElement` is incompatible with the type of `$root`, that is `System.__ComObject`. In the first place, why does `GetRootElement` return `System.__ComObject`, not `IUIAutomationElement`?

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with PowerShell, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'UIAutomationClient'
$ae = [System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement]
$cTrue = [System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition]::TrueCondition
$root = $ae::RootElement
$winNames = $root.FindAll("Children", $cTrue).current.name
```

Comment: This UIAutomationClient is the managed version and outdated compared to the unmanaged version of the dll. The managed powershell example is anyway nice.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet resolved the problem, but finally found an alternative, that is C# Interactive.
I will leave this question for PowerShell users, but, if you can use C# Interactive as an alternative of PowerShell, the following section may help you.

## Approach #5: C# Interactive

1. Install Visual Studio.
2. Generate `Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll` by following the procedures of [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0ad8e71-a2a8-49af-9916-11005ce794ba/creating-some-powershell-cmdlets-for-managing-windows-updates-via-wuapilib#8041782c-9c37-4f3e-a7e7-819a41379809).
3. Run the following script on `csi.exe`.

```cs
#r "Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll"
var uia = new UIAutomationClient.CUIAutomation();
var root = uia.GetRootElement();
var children = root.FindAll(UIAutomationClient.TreeScope.TreeScope_Children, uia.CreateTrueCondition());
```

FYI, C# Interactive works if only the following files exist in the same folder (i.e., you can use C# Interactive anywhere just by bringing the following files from the development environment).

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.exe`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.rsp`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\System.AppContext.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\System.Collections.Immutable.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\System.IO.FileSystem.dll`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll`

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 2** you should get to the interface of

```
IID_IUIAutomation = "{30CBE57D-D9D0-452A-AB13-7AC5AC4825EE}"

CLSID_UIAutomationClient = "{944DE083-8FB8-45CF-BCB7-C477ACB2F897}"
;CoClasses
CLSID_CUIAutomation = "{FF48DBA4-60EF-4201-AA87-54103EEF594E}"
```

MS Doc states

**Remarks**

Every UI Automation client application must obtain this interface to a CUIAutomation object in order to gain access to the functionality of UI Automation.

The following example function creates a CUIAutomation object and obtains the 
    IUIAutomation interface.

```
IUIAutomation *g_pAutomation; 

BOOL InitializeUIAutomation() 
{ 
CoInitialize(NULL); 
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,  
    __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void**)&g_pAutomation); 
return (SUCCEEDED(hr)); 
}
```

I was not able to get it working in PS but maybe this answers helps partly in the right direction (I have it working in AutoIt but that works differently, you can find it with AutoIt IUIAutomation on google)

```
$objCUI=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetTypeFromCLSID("30CBE57D-D9D0-452A-AB13-7AC5AC4825EE")
```

or

```
$Type = [Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID('30CBE57D-D9D0-452A-AB13-7AC5AC4825EE')
$objCUI = [System.Activator]::CreateInstance($Type)
```

both run but when I come to

```
$rootEl = $objCUI.GetType().InvokeMember(
"GetRootElement", 
"InvokeMethod", 
$Null, 
$objCUI, 
@()
)
```

I get errors